# How to detect keypress with no JComponent

Tags: java, swing, detection, keylistener, key-bindings

I'm writing a simple Java code that detects which key is pressed on the keyboard and print it in the console.

I've found only `KeyListener`s and `KeyBinding`s, but I don't think I can use them without a graphical element. How can I detect which keyboard key was pressed if my code has no GUI?

Comment: *...which keyboard key was pressed if my code has no GUI?*, do you mean using a  command line and listen to a key?

Comment: or you just want to sniff a keyboard on a computer? not so fair ;)

Comment: I'd like to sniff MY keyboard, but I don't know if it is possible! ^_^"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to work without any component but you could probably try using following code

```
AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener(){
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
};

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Comment: I've tried this code, but it doesn't work without a focused JComponent! I need something else!